# about power of $2 \times 2$ matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

1. Let $A= \pmatrix{10&25\\ 0&-10}$. Find $A^{100}$.
2. Let $B \in M_2(\mathbb{R})$. For which $ x > 0$ can we have $B^{100}= \pmatrix{-1&0\\ 0&-1-x}$?

For case one I find $A^2={10}^2 I$ and $A^4={10}^4 I$ ... then $A^{100}={10}^{100} I$.

For case two $\det(B^{100})=1+x$ and $B $ is invertible matrix.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @PeterPhipps.I can't find $x$ and is my solution true for "1" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hints:**

Diagonalize $A$:
$$A = \pmatrix{1 & -5 \\ 0 & 4}\pmatrix{10 & 0 \\ 0 & -10}\pmatrix{1 & -5 \\ 0 & 4}^{-1}$$

so
$$A^{100} = \pmatrix{1 & -5 \\ 0 & 4}\pmatrix{10^{100} & 0 \\ 0 & (-10)^{100}}\pmatrix{1 & -5 \\ 0 & 4}^{-1}$$

---

I'm reading the second question like this.

$B \in M_2(\mathbb{R})$ is given. For which $x > 0$ is $B^{100} = \pmatrix{-1&0\\ 0&-1-x}$ possible?

We know that $$\{-1, -1-x\} = \sigma(B^{100}) = \sigma(B)^{100}$$ so there exists $\lambda \in  \sigma(B)$ such that $\lambda^{100} = -1$. It has to be $\lambda \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{R}$, but then since $B$ is a real matrix, we know that also $\overline{\lambda} \in \sigma(B)$. Hence, $\sigma(B) = \{\lambda, \overline{\lambda}\}$. But then $\sigma(B)^{100} = \{-1\}$ so $x = 0$.

Hence, no such $x > 0$ exists.

Comment: What is mean of :$\{-1, -1-x\} = \sigma(B^{100}) = \sigma(B)^{100}$ ? What is definition of sigma?

Comment: @amirbahadory $\sigma(B)$ is the set of eigenvalues of $B$. $\sigma(B)^{100}$ is a notation for $\{\mu^{100} : \mu \in \sigma(B)\}$.